# How to create a Mat object with 3 dimensions?

Tags: c++, opencv

I used it:

Mat map( img.size(), CV_8UC3, CV_RGB(0,0,0) );

but it seems not create any matrix with 3 dimensions!
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The good way to do that is to use the appropriated constructor :

```
Mat::Mat(int ndims, const int* sizes, int type)
```

For example if you want to create a 100x60x15 matrix :

```
int sz[] = {100, 60, 15};
Mat map(3, sz, CV_8U);
```

Answer (score 1):

The CV_8UC3 flag means that you are creating an image that has three channels where each pixel in each channel is represented as an unsigned character. You should be able to confirm the multiple channels (or 3rd dimension) by seeing the output of

```
 map.channels();
```

which will return how large the matrix is in the third dimension. If you require more channels, then use something like:

```
 map.create(100,60,CV_8UC(15));
```

where 15 is the number of channels.

Comment: Mat channels and dimensions are different concerns: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a39cf614aa52567e9a945cd2609bd767b